# Usage of getStaticPaths with dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have an index page which I show movies by sections (trending movies, popular movies, etc.) and I am calling **different** api urls inside `getStaticProps` for that. Now in `[movieId].js` page, I am using `getStaticPaths` since I am using dynamic route. But what I don't understand is user can click on **any** movie item on **any** section but because of I need to get the paths for all the possible movies in `[movideId].js` page and return as `paths` in `getStaticPaths`,

How would I know which section a user has clicked so I can call that specific api in `getStaticPaths` to get the correct data and return the correct paths?

This is my codes

```
// index.js 

export default function Home(props) {

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>Trending</h1>
        {props.trending.results.map((movie, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <Link href={`/movie/${movie.id}`}>
                <a>{movie.original_title}</a>
              </Link>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1>Popular</h1>
        {props.popular.results.map((movie, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <Link href={`/movie/${movie.id}`}>
                <a>{movie.original_title}</a>
              </Link>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


export async function getStaticProps() {
  try {
    const token = '...';

    const [trendingRes, popularRes] = await Promise.all([
      fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=${token}`
      ),
      fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${token}&language=en-US&page=1`
      )
    ]);

    const [trending, popular] = await Promise.all([
      trendingRes.json(),
      popularRes.json()
    ]);

    return { props: { trending, popular } };
  } catch (err) {
      return { notFound: true };
  }
}

// [movieId].js

export async function getStaticPaths() {

  const token = "...";
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=${token}` // here I am hardcoding to call trending api url no matter which section a user has clicked on 
  );
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    paths: data.results.map((d) => ({ params: { movieId: d.id.toString() } }))
  };
}
```

[Full Code sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-bbvtzg?file=pages/index.js)

Now if a user clicks on a movie of `popular` section, it shows 404 not found page as I only have data and paths from trending api url.

I am still learning nextjs so hopefully my explanation is understandable, free free to ask more detail about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In real life if you have large data set you would not want to prerender all the possible combinations and all possible movie pages.

Luckily there is a `fallback` flag for `getStaticPaths`.

You can use `fallback: blocking` ([docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-blocking)), that way if the key of the page was not specified in `getStaticPaths` the page will be generated (and cached) after the first request. But you need  an api where you can just fetch movie by id. You have it, so all you need to do is change `fallback` key. [Check this Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions68319423?file=pages/movie/%5BmovieId%5D.js)

If you don't have such an api you can for example split your routes and have `/trending/[id]` route and `popular/[id]` route. That way you would always know from where you need to fetch your movies.

Hope it makes sense, feel free to ask other questions.

Comment: You mentioned `if you have large data set you would not want to prerender all the possible combinations and all possible movie pages.`, does it mean it's better to split the routes and have different route as you suggested for a better practice ?

Comment: No, what I mean is that if you have 100k movies then you don't want to make 100k prerendered pages at build time, it would be silly.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Given your mentioned examples, I wouldn't use `getStaticPaths` but `getServerSideProps`, since the `getStaticPaths` use case is only for when you have a handful of pages that you want to generate statically.

Inside `getServerSideProps` you will have access to the `context` object. Then, accessing `context.query` will get you whatever the dynamic path of your page contains.

To give you an example:

In the `pages` folder of your Next.js project, create a folder called `movies`, and then create a `[id].js` inside of it.

This will match paths such as:

```
/movies/1
/movies/123
/movies/456
```

And then you can use the dynamic path (i.e. `123`) to call your API and fetch the specific movie.